# error: LNK 2005 when i include regex, vector, or curlpp in c++ CLR

Tags: user-interface, visual-c++, lnk

I'm new to C++ CLR development. I'm trying to develop a GUI app but when i include vector/regex/curlpp i get an error while compiling LNK 2005. Anyone have any idea how to get around this problem.

I'm using visual studio 2022 version

MyForm.h

```
#pragma once

namespace Calculator {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox3;
    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(18, 27);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(72, 29);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(194, 27);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(72, 29);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, static_cast<System::Drawing::FontStyle>((System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold | System::Drawing::FontStyle::Italic)),
                System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(96, 32);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(88, 20);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 2;
            this->label1->Text = L"Operation";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(117, 55);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(45, 43);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 3;
            this->button1->Text = L"+";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this->button2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(117, 104);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(45, 43);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 4;
            this->button2->Text = L"-";
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button2_Click);
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this->button3->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(117, 153);
            this->button3->Name = L"button3";
            this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(45, 43);
            this->button3->TabIndex = 5;
            this->button3->Text = L"*";
            this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button3->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button3_Click);
            // 
            // button4
            // 
            this->button4->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->button4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(117, 202);
            this->button4->Name = L"button4";
            this->button4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(45, 43);
            this->button4->TabIndex = 6;
            this->button4->Text = L"/";
            this->button4->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button4->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button4_Click);
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this->textBox3->Enabled = false;
            this->textBox3->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(18, 251);
            this->textBox3->Name = L"textBox3";
            this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(248, 29);
            this->textBox3->TabIndex = 7;
            this->textBox3->Text = L"Result";
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 293);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        int output = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox1->Text) + System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox2->Text);
        textBox3->Text = System::Convert::ToString(output);
    }
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        int output = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox1->Text) - System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox2->Text);
        textBox3->Text = System::Convert::ToString(output);
}
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        int output = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox1->Text) * System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox2->Text);
        textBox3->Text = System::Convert::ToString(output);
}
private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        double output = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text) / System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text);
        textBox3->Text = System::Convert::ToString(output);
}
};
}
```

MyForm.cpp

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;

using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]

void main(array<String^>^ args)

{

    Application::EnableVisualStyles();

    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Calculator::MyForm form;

    Application::Run(% form);

}
```

when i compile this i get this error
[Error i get when i compile the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koH8t.png)

Kindly help me fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please [edit] your question to include a [mre] as well as a copy-paste (as text) of the actual errors you get.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.